# Is it an antipattern to consume 100 topic in round robin style?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to consume several topics one at-a-time in sequences, within the same program. Each topic would be consumed for a few seconds, and then the program would pass to the next one.

In pseudo-python, what I want to do is something like this:

```
last_partition_offsets_per_topic = {}
while True:
   for topic in topics:
      (last_partition_offsets, message_batch) = get_last_messages_from_topic(topic, last_partition_offsets_per_topic.get(offset))
      last_partition_offsets_per_topic[topic] = last_partition_offsets 
      process(topic, message_batch)
```

I would like to know if there are things I need to know about the impact on performance
when consuming kafka with such a pattern.